# Never seen this before -2106F

Tags: mac

Trying to update my Mac and I’m getting  -2106F. What does this mean!?

[image]

Comment: You are unlikely to see that from simply "updating" the machine. It's a 'can't connect' message usually only seen on Internet Recovery. Please clarify.

Comment: @Tetsujin is most likely correct. I would suggest 2.4Ghz network or possible. I have had trouble using 5Ghz networks with internet recovery.

Answer (score -2):

A quick Google search led me to this : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7939592

> The suggestion on the page is to try Internet Recovery mode, and that from there to check the hard disk. There is a comment further down where the user says they were finally able to connect to Internet Recovery

However, it does sound quite possible that you have a bad drive (SSD or hard disk). Contact Apple to see what your options are regarding a replacement/repair.

Comment: This is a "link only" answer that should be either edited with steps to perform, or better yet left as a comment instead.

Comment: Except for the bit after the link where I mentioned that it sounds like a bad drive.

Comment: What exactly should the OP try? This seems to be hidden somewhere in the discussion thread on the linked page.

Comment: The suggestion on the page is to try Internet Recovery mode, and that from there to check the hard disk. There is a comment further down where the user says they were finally able to connect to Internet Recovery